# Clear SingleChoice ListView selection

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android

Is there a way to clear the selected item in a ListView?

The ListView is defined like this:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/example_list"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>
```

And is filled using a custom Adapter.

The selected item is highlighted using a Selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape>
      <gradient
       android:startColor="#3E5260"
         android:endColor="#3E5260"
         android:angle="270" />
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item android:state_activated="true">
    <shape>
      <gradient
       android:startColor="#3E5260"
         android:endColor="#3E5260"
         android:angle="270" />
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

Now what I really have is 2 ListViews in a single activity and when an item is
selected in one ListView I want to deselect the item in the other ListView.

Both ListViews raise the following handler when an item is clicked:

```
void DeviceList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //easy enough to check which ListView raised the event
    //but then I need to deselect the selected item in the other listview
}
```

I've tried things like:

```
exampleList.SetItemChecked(exampleList.SelectedItemPosition, false);
```

and

```
exampleList.SetSelection(-1);
```

But that does not seem to work.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48253761/1015595

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Using `listView.SetItemChecked(-1, true);` works fine here.

Here is my Activity I tested with:

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
var listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView);
_listAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(this);
listView.Adapter = _listAdapter;

var button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.removeChoice);
button.Click += (sender, args) => listView.SetItemChecked(-1, true);
```

Main.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
  />
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/removeChoice"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="remove choice"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is => notation?  I have never seen that used in android code.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky It is a lambda expression, an anonymous method. This is C#. In Java you have the `IOnClickListener` implementations.

Comment: @Cheesebaron  And your code actually compiles?  I'm curious why you sprinkled some C# in an Android question...

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Do you notice the `monodroid` tag? Try look up what that is :)

Comment: it throws an exception under the hood. bad solution.

Comment: @agamov what do you mean?

Comment: @Cheesebaron I can see exception stacktrace in LogCat, although the solution is working. but `clearChoices()` suggested by @ianhanniballake works without spoiling logcat with exceptions.

Answer (score 19):

Use [clearChoices()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#clearChoices%28%29) to clear the checked state of all items in a ListView

Comment: I've tried that as well but does not seem to work (should note I'm using Mono for Android)

Comment: It seems that you should call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after this to make it work.

Comment: After calling `listView.clearChoices()` you may need to call `listView.requestLayout()`. See [this excellent explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48294683/1015595) for more.

Answer (score 2):

Its works simple for me:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.idMyListView);
         listView.clearFocus();
```

Comment: Why would clearFocus() clear a single-choice ListView?  Makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question, but just in case someone else needs it in the future, based on @Cheesebaron answer, here's what I did:

On each ListViews' `OnItemClickListener` set the other's list checked item to false:

```
list1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            list2.setItemChecked(list2.getSelectedItemPosition(), false);
        }
});
```

This implementation is in Java, but if you get the logic here you can implement it in C# as well. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE / singleChoice

```
int v = listView.getCheckedItemPosition();
if (v >= 0)
    listView.setItemChecked(v, false);
```

Comment: Not a single technique on this entire page has helped me clear the selection emphasis (a gray background) from my ListView...

Comment: I went with the "Dirty Fix" here. Limited use application... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48253761/how-do-i-clear-listview-selection